# Are "rather than" and "instead of" exchangeable?

Tags: meaning

i am learning this [Stanford](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuyk1nLMhRm6WkyV2sFP81ENNnsnydcm_) course

the professor is [saying](https://youtu.be/QzN4cSH71D0?t=300)

> x-ray in the hospital is a digital image rather than a physical piece
>   of film

it seems that "rather than" could be substituted by "instead of" in this sentence.

are "rather than" and "instead of" exchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"instead" implies that one item must be used instead of the other.

"rather than" implies that one material means "one of the two items is closer to the truth / reality than the other".

---

"Instead" is associated usually with "to use" (or similar):

> **Use** X **instead of** Y
>
> **Drink** water **instead of** alcohol

---

"Rather than" is associated usually with "to be" (or similar):

> A **is** B **rather than** C
>
> x-ray in the hospital **is** a digital image **rather than** a physical piece of film
>
> **Choose** to be healthy **rather than** to be beautiful